# What is causing this error in WP while using get_user_meta?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding additional metadata to users in WordPress and every time I use `get_user_meta` I'm getting this error: `Notice: Object of class WP_User could not be converted to int in /.../wp-includes/functions.php on line 2999`

My code is

```
foreach( $metadata as $key => $value ) {

        if ( !get_user_meta( $wcm_users[$i], $key, '' ) ) {

            add_user_meta( $wcm_users[$i]->ID, $key, '' );

        }

    }
```

$metadata is an array of additional metadata I want to add, so its a basic check to see if the metadata is already added, if not, add in. Can't understand what's triggering the error. If I remove the `get_user_meta` the error goes away.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) takes an integer ID. You're passing it a `WP_User` object. Try:

```
    foreach( $metadata as $key => $value ) {

        if ( !get_user_meta( $wcm_users[$i]->ID, $key, '' ) ) {

            add_user_meta( $wcm_users[$i]->ID, $key, '' );

        }

    }
```

Also, note that the third (optional) parameter to `get_user_meta()` is a boolean to indicate if you want to treat the value as a single value or an array—I'm guessing you should just be leaving it off to get the default behaviour of a single value. That's what the empty string you're passing will be doing (as an empty string is a boolean false) but it's not that obvious from your code.

Also, [`update_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) will add the meta if it doesn't exist, and update it if it does, which is what you say you want to do, so:

```
foreach( $metadata as $key => $value ) {
    update_user_meta( $wcm_users[$i]->ID, $key, '' );
}
```

...will probably do what you want, anyway.

Comment: It was indeed the case! Thanks!

Comment: I can't accept the answer just yet (need to wait 10 min). Will do shortly.

Comment: No problem. I've added what's probably a cleaner solution to my answer, too.

Comment: Great! That sounds neater!